# What is the sentence structure? Specific use of gerund

Tags: sentence-construction, difference, subordinate-clauses

> Even after **lowering the volume**, Suzanne found that her electric
>   guitar so annoyed her neighbours that they complained to the building's
>   manager

Why is the gerund used here? What sentence structure is this? I always felt the urge to change such sentences to something like:

> Even after **she lowered the volume**, Suzanne found that her electric
>   guitar so annoyed her neighbours that they complained to the building's
>   manager

Comment: It's called present participle clause, and you prefer to convert it into a subordinate clause (with its own subject and predicate).

Comment: or "even after she *had lowered* the volume" to reflect the past relative to another past in the sentence and also the completed aspect of the action taken.

Comment: What is special about this use of a gerund? A gerund can be used after a preposition:  Water is good for washing.

Comment: @VictorBazarov Thanks Mate! Reading about the usage of the present participle clause and subordinate clauses right now. Thanks folks for the other responses too.